# Is there a Micropython library for Adafruit's TLC5947?

Tags: module, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm working on a RPi Pico W based project, and I need to use a TLC5947 led driver. The connection is SPI, which I'm told is pretty simple, but I tried to implement it myself and couldn't. Adafruit has a circuitpython module, but it dosen't seem to translate (directly at least) into micropython.

Do I need to keep researching making it myself or is there a module already made?

My attempt: (I assume `write` or `pwmbuffer` is the problem fwiw. Comments are copied directly from Adafruit's C++ version of the library for arduino.)

```py
from machine import Pin
import machine

class TLC5947:
    def __init__(self, clock: int = 2, data: int = 3, latch: int = 5):
        self.numdrivers = 1
        self.data = Pin(data, Pin.OUT)
        self.clock = Pin(clock, Pin.OUT)
        self.latch = Pin(latch, Pin.OUT)
        
        self.latch.low()

        self._spi = machine.SPI(0)

        # self.OE = OE

        self.pwmbuffer = [0] * (24 * 2 * self.numdrivers)         # memset(pwmbuffer, 0, 2 * 24 * n);
        # self.spi = machine.SPI(0)

    def write(self):
        self.latch.low()                                        #        digitalWrite(_lat, LOW);
                                                                #            // 24 channels per TLC5974
        for c in range(24 * self.numdrivers - 1, -1, -1):       #            for (int16_t c = 24 * numdrivers - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
                                                                #                // 12 bits per channel, send MSB first
            for b in range(11, -1, -1):                         #                for (int8_t b = 11; b >= 0; b--) {
                self.clock.low()                                #                    digitalWrite(_clk, LOW);
                if self.pwmbuffer[c] & (1 << b):                #                    if (pwmbuffer[c] & (1 << b))
                    self.data.high()                            #                        digitalWrite(_dat, HIGH);
                else:                                           #                    else
                    self.data.low()                             #                        digitalWrite(_dat, LOW);
                                                                #
                self.clock.high()                               #                    digitalWrite(_clk, HIGH);
                                                                #                }
                                                                #            }
        self.clock.low()                                        #        digitalWrite(_clk, LOW);
        self.latch.high()                                       #        digitalWrite(_lat, HIGH);
        self.latch.low()                                        #        digitalWrite(_lat, LOW);

    def setLed(self, lednum, r,g,b):
        self.setPWM(lednum * 3, r)
        self.setPWM(lednum * 3 + 1, g)
        self.setPWM(lednum * 3 + 2, b)

    def setPWM(self, chan: int, pwm: int):
        if (pwm > 4095):
            pwm = 4095
        try:
            self.pwmbuffer[chan] = pwm
        except:
            pass
```

Edit:
Got it. That repo refers to a folder structure like this:

```
project/
├── modules/
 │   └──tlc5947-rgb-micropython/
 │       ├──...
 │       └──micropython.mk
└── micropython/
    ├──ports/
   ... ├──stm32/
      ...
```

But I don't have anything like that. Mine is:

```
project/
|_ .vscode/
|    |_ ...
|_ lib/
|_ code.py
|_ i2c_display.py
|_ tlc5947_ME.py
|_ .picowgo # Used by Pico-W-Go vscode extention to allow Pico programming in vscode
```

Answer (score 0):

Via [Awesome MicroPython](https://awesome-micropython.com/), I found https://gitlab.com/peterzuger/tlc5947-rgb-micropython - it looks fairly up-to-date.